"solana-test-validator" initialization error issue
enter image description here- Why have I run the command "solana-test-validator" for more than 1 hour without success?, my wifi and computer configuration are strong enough to run Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS software.
I hope everyone will help me find a solution to handle this problem, thank you.
